# What is a functional way to accumulate values from callback into a list?

Tags: haskell, callback, functional-programming, immutability

I'm interoping with a C function that I pass a (callback) function to and it calls it every-time with a different parameter.

I imported it into Haskell and now I have something like this (I've simplified it, of course):

```
countToFive :: (Int -> IO ()) -> IO ()
countToFive fn = do fn 1; fn 2; fn 3; fn 4; fn 5
```

I want to make a list of every number passed to `fn`; something with this signature:

```
counting :: IO [Int]
```

That in the example above will (perform the IO, of course) with the result of `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

The imperative approach of `counting` would be to create a mutable list, and call `countToFive` with a function that inserts the parameter into the mutable list on every-call, and then just return the list.

What's the functional way to go about it?

Comment: That `return ()` at the end of the line is 100% redundant.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your imperative version. Are the numbers `[1..5]` known at compile time, or are they generated somewhere at runtime? If runtime, have you got a function of type `IO Int` that you want to use repeatedly to produce the next number to feed in to `fn`? I guess my question boils down to "Why not just do `count' fn = mapM_ fn [1..5] >> return [1..5]` or provide a `fn` modifier `applyAndReturn :: (a -> IO ()) -> a -> IO a` defined as `applyAndReturn fn a = fn a >> return a` and then `count'' fn = mapM (applyAndReturn fn) [1..5]`?"

Comment: Or do you want to define a single `fn` as a setter `::Int->IO()` and a correspending getter `::IO [Int]`? If so, please edit the question to ask "How do I define `fn` and `counting` so that `countToFive fn >> counting` returns `[a,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: @AndrewC All the information is from runtime, literally all I know is that I pass a function and it will be called multiple times with the elements I need as described.

Comment: OK, but are you trying to define `fn` or a variant of `coountToFive`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the exact same way—once you're living so deeply in the `IO` monad many things will feel a great deal like its imperative cousin.

```
import Data.IORef

counting :: ((Int -> IO ()) -> IO ()) -> IO [Int]
counting fun = do
  store <- newIORef []
  fun (\new -> modifyIORef store (new:))
  readIORef store
```

Note the use of rather higher order function types to parameterize `counting` over functions of the type of `countToFive`. For an even more mind-bending experience it's interesting to note that this method is consistent with "continuation passing style". In a very real sense `countToFive` "contains" a list of integers and simply has a tricky method of "getting it out".

Comment: Been looking for something like `IORef` for so long! thank you very much.